# Listening when new records are added to the store via a computer property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am pushing records into my store using websockets.

I am displaying items on the screen via a handlebars template

```
{{#each item in items}}
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

In my controller I have the items collection

```
items : function() {
   var items = this.store.find('items');
   return items.filterBy({type : "NEW"});
}.property()
```

Now, when new records are added to the store, I need to update the items automatically.

```
items : function() {
   var items = this.store.find('items');
   return items.filterBy({type : "NEW"});
}.property('??????')
```

So is there some way of listening to the store when records are added via a computed property.  Ideally I would like to listen to models of a particular type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to do:

```
items : function() {
  return this.store.filter(function(item){
      return item.get('TYPE') === 'NEW';
  });
}.property()
```

`store.filter` returns a live array that updates whenever there are any changes in the store, so it will respond to the new records beings pushed.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you are using an array controller. You just need to observe the content array like `content.[]`. So your controller code should look like

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  filteredContent: function() {
    return this.get('model').filterBy('type', 0);
  }.property('model.[]')
});
```

And use the `filteredContent` in the template

```
{{#each filteredContent}}
  <li>{{title}} - {{songCount}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

[**Here is a working bin.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kujol/1/edit)

Comment: Actually, I am using an ObjectController.  The screen is a drag and drop screen which is kind of complicated.

Comment: Well the concept is the same. IF 'items' is an array. You create a CP with another name like 'filteredItems' and 'items.[]' as the dependent key. Use the 'filteredItems' in the template instead of items.

Comment: But what if new data is added to the `store` via an ember-data `push()`.  How will my local controller array we aware of this new data in the store?  That is the issue I am having.