# How to filterBy but keep databinding in order using ember.js

Tags: ember.js

extending upon this question [How to properly setup a store that acts as a single pointer across your web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392921/how-to-properly-setup-a-store-that-acts-as-a-single-pointer-across-your-web-app)

I'd like to apply a filter to the "getEverything" method to filter by an associated id (look at the actions setup in my route below)

```
var PeoplePersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var store = this.get('store');
        var person = Person.findById(store, params.person_id);
        var actions = Action.findByPerson(store, params.person_id);
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({person: person, actions: actions});
    },
    setupController: function(controller, hash) {
        controller.set('model', hash.person);
        controller.set('actions', hash.actions);
    }
});
```

The findByPerson method for action looks like this

```
findByPerson: function(store, person_id) {
    var everything = store.getEverything('action');
    return everything.filterBy('person_id', parseInt(person_id, 10));
}
```

When I add a new "action" in my controller like so

```
var PeoplePersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        submit: function() {
            var person_id = this.get('model.id');
            var opened = this.get('opened');
            var newAction = Action.create({opened: opened, person_id: person_id});
            this.store.push('action', newAction);
        }
    }
});
```

it will not show the newly added item (until I navigate away/ and back)

How can I modify the findByPerson method to make sure I get a databound array?

Comment: Not sure. May be this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/25336040/548568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly the easiest solution I can think of is to create a computed property based off of the everything model.

```
var arr = Em.ArrayProxy.extend({
  source: model,
  content: function () {
    return this.get('source').filterBy('color', 'red');
  }.property('source.@each.color')
}).create();
```

Since you are creating this properties on the fly, you could tack in totally different properties to watch, if you wanted to extend the idea past just the single use case shown here.

```
var person_id = parseInt(person_id, 10);

return Em.ArrayProxy.extend({
  source: undefined,
  content: function () {
    var filter_id = this.get('filter_id');
    return this.get('source').filterBy('person_id', filter_id);
  }.property('source.@each.person_id')
}).create({
  filter_id: person_id,
  source: everything
});
```

Ember Data does it slightly different.  They keep track of all of the collections that are filtering based on that type.  If a new one enters or leaves the store, they trigger an update on those collections.  (at least that's how it was last time I looked at it).

Here's a dummy example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/veqete/3/edit